# Backbone router: initialize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i've seen that the function initialize in my router is called every time i come back to the home page and not one time at start of application. Why?

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "user/:id":"userDetails",
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.update_my_activity();
    },

    home: function() {
        if (Parse.User.current()) {
            console.log("loggato");

            var user=new Person();
            user.savePosition();

            new BarraScreamView();
            new MenuView();
            var self=this;

            console.log("inrouterhome");
            Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
            Models.utenti.fetch({
                success: function(object) {
                    console.log(object);
                    var page=new Homelistuser({model:object});
                    self.changePage(page);
                },

                error: function(amici, error) {
                }
            });

        } else
            new LoginView();
    }




       changePage: function (page) {
   this.update_my_activity(); 
   $('#pagina').empty();


    page.render();
    $('#pagina').append($(page.el));
  },
```

Comment: Initialize is called when the AppRouter is new'd up, regardless of `App.start()`. Where do you new up your AppRouter?

Comment: Your router code is incomplete; we don't see the whole `home` function. All it should do is log 'loggato' if the user object is up to date (I assume that's the point of `Parse.User.current()`). What else happens in the `home` route?

Comment: Would you also include `changePage` please? Also, what's the console.log when you exercise the `home` route?

Comment: console.log when i exercise the home route is logged if user is logged

Comment: The first line of `changePage` is the same as the `AppRouter`'s `initialize` function, so might *look like* the router's being re-initialized when it isn't. What makes you think the `initialize` function is being called too?